# Serial Voting page in Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, serial-voting

The [Serial Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) page of Help Center has a couple of minor issues. First, it opens with two nearly-identical headers on top of each other:

> [image]

I understand they are different levels (h2 and h3), but the difference being small, and headers being long, the combination becomes  a mess of repetitive bold. No other page of Help Center has two consecutive headers like this one.

One easy fix would be to drop h3 header. Another would be to change h2 header  to **Serial Voting**.

Also, there is an over-edited sentence in the first paragraph: "*systematic targetting voting*". I suppose it means  *systematic targeted voting*.